# USB-C drivers for Lenovo ThinkVision X1

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, lenovo, webcam

I am using a System76 galaga pro running Ubuntu 20.04 with a Lenovo Thinkvision X1 (2nd gen) monitor. I can use the monitor itself via HDMI cable with no problem. But the integrated webcam will only work with the USB-C cable.
I have tried using fwupdmgr, but there don't seem to be any drivers for the monitor.
Is there anywhere else I could look or tools I could try?

Comment: Does the webcam appear in the output of `lsusb`? 

Comment: No it doesn't. And now I have to add more words for a simple no to be accepted.